# How to change scheduling time while the app is running

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I,m trying to have a pop up window appear at the time set by the user. The window appears at whatever time that I have precoded and I have to input a value as the app cannot run without there being a pre set time.

main.py

```
class MainApp(App):
    hour = NumericProperty(17) # I would receive an error if I was to put None here
    minute = 40

    def build(self):
        schedule.every().day.at(str(self.hour) + ":" + str(self.minute)).do(self.mantraPop_message)
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: schedule.run_pending(), 1)
        return MainScreen()
```

kv file. This is what I want to happen when a number has been clicked

```
            LabelButton:
                id: six
                text: '16'
                font_size: 25
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                on_release: app.hour = int(six.text)
                on_release: print(app.hour)
```